Gstreamer linking videomixer request pads not working
I'm trying to link the sink request pad from videomixer to a videobox element like in here How to program videomixer using Gstreamer C API . But I'm getting a strange error
stack exec gtk-intro-twelve-exe
Usage: gtk-intro-twelve-exe.EXE <video filename>

(gtk-intro-twelve-exe.EXE:19764): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 15:55:44.215: Element mix already has a pad named sink_1, the behaviour of  gst_element_get_request_pad() for existing pads is undefined!

(gtk-intro-twelve-exe.EXE:19764): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 15:55:44.215: Padname sink_1 is not unique in element mix, not adding
Error: Internal data stream error.

(gtk-intro-twelve-exe.EXE:19764): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 15:55:44.340: gst_element_release_request_pad: assertion 'GST_PAD_PARENT (pad) == element' failed
Now playing: 
Returned, stopping playback
Unreffing the request pad
Deleting pipeline

This is my code
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLabels  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

-- This is a translation of the Hello World gstreamer example to haskell
-- Original C source:
-- https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/helloworld.html
-- Written by Jaro Reinders on 2017-01-09
--
-- All comments are copied from the source C code

import qualified GI.GLib as GLib
import qualified GI.Gst  as Gst

import Data.GI.Base.Properties (setObjectPropertyInt32, setObjectPropertyString, setObjectPropertyDouble)

import Control.Monad (void, when, forever)
import Control.Concurrent
import System.Environment
import System.IO (stderr)
import System.Exit (exitFailure)
import Data.Text (pack, unpack)
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

busCall :: GLib.MainLoop -> Gst.Bus -> Gst.Message -> IO Bool
busCall loop _bus message = do
  messageTypes <- Gst.getMessageType message

  when (Gst.MessageTypeEos `elem` messageTypes) $ do
    putStrLn "End of stream"
    GLib.mainLoopQuit loop
    
  when (Gst.MessageTypeNewClock `elem` messageTypes) $ do
    putStrLn "New Clock"
    --(gerror,_debug) <- Gst.messageParseError message
    --T.hPutStrLn stderr . ("Error: " <>) =<< Gst.gerrorMessage gerror
    --GLib.mainLoopQuit loop

  when (Gst.MessageTypeClockLost `elem` messageTypes) $ do
    putStrLn "Clock Lost"

  when (Gst.MessageTypeError `elem` messageTypes) $ do
    (gerror,_debug) <- Gst.messageParseError message
    T.hPutStrLn stderr . ("Error: " <>) =<< Gst.gerrorMessage gerror
    GLib.mainLoopQuit loop

  return True

onPadAdded :: Gst.Element -> Gst.Pad -> IO ()
onPadAdded sink pad = do
  -- We can now link this pad with the vorbis-decoder sink pad
  putStrLn "Dynamic pad created, linking demuxer/decoder"
  Just sinkPad <- Gst.elementGetStaticPad sink "sink"
  void $ Gst.padLink pad sinkPad

main :: IO ()
main = do
  progName <- getProgName
  args <- getArgs

  -- Initialization
  void $ Gst.init Nothing

  --pipeline <- Gst.parseLaunch "filesrc name=my_filesrc ! mad ! osssink"
  --print pipeline

  loop <- GLib.mainLoopNew Nothing False

  -- Check input arguments
  when (length args /= 1) $ do
    T.hPutStrLn stderr $ "Usage: " <> pack progName <> " <video filename>"
    --exitFailure
  --let filename = head args

  --let methodname = last args

  -- Create gstreamer elements
  pipeline <- Gst.pipelineNew (Just "video-player")

  let makeElement factoryname name =
        fromMaybe (error $ unpack $ "Could not create " <> name)
        <$> Gst.elementFactoryMake factoryname (Just name)

  --test    <- makeElement  "videotestsrc"  "testsrc"
  source  <- makeElement  "filesrc"       "filesrc"
  source2 <- makeElement  "filesrc"       "filesrc2"
  --demuxer <- makeElement  "qtdemux"       "qt-demuxer"
  decode  <- makeElement  "decodebin"     "decoder"
  --queuer  <- makeElement  "queue"         "queuer"
  conv    <- makeElement  "videoconvert"  "converter"
  --conv2   <- makeElement  "videoconvert"  "converter2"
  box     <- makeElement  "videobox"      "videoboxer"
  box2    <- makeElement  "videobox"      "videoboxer2"
  mixer   <- makeElement  "videomixer"    "mix"
  --mixer2   <- makeElement  "videomixer"    "mix2"
  --alpha   <- makeElement  "alpha"         "transparency"
  sink    <- makeElement  "d3dvideosink"  "video-output"
  

  -- Set up the pipeline

  -- we set the input filename to the source element
  --setObjectPropertyString source2 "location" (Just $ pack filename)
  setObjectPropertyString source  "location" (Just "12_24.mov")
  setObjectPropertyString source2 "location" (Just "0_12.mov")
  setObjectPropertyDouble box     "border-alpha" 0.0
  setObjectPropertyInt32  box     "right" 0
  setObjectPropertyDouble box2    "border-alpha" 0.0
  setObjectPropertyInt32  box2    "left" 0
  --setObjectPropertyString source2 "location" (Just $ pack arg)
  --setObjectPropertyInt32 alpha "method" 2

  --caps <- Gst.capsNewAny
  
  -- we add a message handler
  bus <- Gst.pipelineGetBus pipeline
  busWatchId <- Gst.busAddWatch bus GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT (busCall loop)

  -- we add all elements into the pipeline
  -- file-source | decoder | converter | alsa-output
  mapM_ (Gst.binAdd pipeline) [source, decode, conv, box, mixer, source2, box2, sink]

  

  -- we link the elements together
  -- file-source -> ogg-demuxer ~> vorbis-decoder -> converter -> alsa-output
  {-void $ Gst.elementLink source decode

  void $ Gst.elementLink source2 decode-}
  {-void $ Gst.elementLink source decode
  void $ Gst.elementLink decode conv
  void $ Gst.elementLink conv box
  void $ Gst.elementLink box mixer

  void $ Gst.elementLink source2 decode
  void $ Gst.elementLink decode conv
  void $ Gst.elementLink conv box2
  void $ Gst.elementLink box2 mixer

  void $ Gst.elementLink mixer sink-}
  
  let elementLinkMany (a:b:cs) = (&&) <$> Gst.elementLink a b <*> elementLinkMany (b:cs)
      elementLinkMany _ = return True

  void $ elementLinkMany [source, decode, conv, box, mixer, sink]
  void $ elementLinkMany [source2, decode, conv, box2, mixer, sink]

  mixerSinkPadTemplate <- Gst.elementGetPadTemplate mixer "sink_%u"

  mixerSinkPadTemplate <- case mixerSinkPadTemplate of
    Nothing -> fail "whoops, dying"
    Just mixerSinkPadTemplate -> pure mixerSinkPadTemplate
  
  mixerSinkPad <- Gst.elementRequestPad mixer mixerSinkPadTemplate (Just "sink_1") Nothing

  mixerSinkPad <- case mixerSinkPad of
    Nothing -> fail "whoops, dying again"
    Just mixerSinkPad -> pure mixerSinkPad

  Just boxPad <- Gst.elementGetStaticPad box "src"

  void $ Gst.padLink boxPad mixerSinkPad

  Just box2Pad <- Gst.elementGetStaticPad box2 "src"

  void $ Gst.padLink box2Pad mixerSinkPad

  -- Set the pipeline to "playing" state
  putStrLn $ "Now playing: " {-++ filename-}
  void $ Gst.elementSetState pipeline Gst.StatePlaying

  -- Iterate
  #run loop
  
  -- Out of the main loop, clean up nicely
  putStrLn "Returned, stopping playback"
  void $ Gst.elementSetState pipeline Gst.StateNull

  -- Unref the request pad
  putStrLn "Unreffing the request pad"
  void $ Gst.elementReleaseRequestPad mixer mixerSinkPad
  void $ Gst.objectUnref mixerSinkPad

  putStrLn "Deleting pipeline"
  void $ GLib.sourceRemove busWatchId

I don't understand what I'm supposed to do. I've noticed Rubndsouza's answer to the post might be wrong? Since he's saying to connect the source pad of ffmpegcolorspace to the sink pad of videomixer. But how can this be when the source element is put after the sink one like so gst_element_link_many (source1, filter, videobox1, mixer, clrspace, sink); ? Shouldn't the videomixer element connect to its precedent element rather than the successive one through Gst.padLink function? Since sink pads are on the left and source pads are on the right.
Am I understanding something wrong?
The gstreamer error is telling me that the videomixer element already has a pad named sink_1 but I don't know how to procede from there.
